# Undefined variable in angular using IONIC framework

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Im trying to set values from a JSON response into some variables. But the value is not set and returns "undefined" when trying to see the values in Console.log().

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
public data: any;
carbs: string;
fat:any;
protein:any;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public userprovider: UserProvider) {

    //returns json array
    this.user = this.userprovider.getUser(userid);

    this.user.toPromise().then(res => {

        this.carbs = res[0].carbs;
        this.fat = res[0].fat;
        this.protein = res[0].protein;

    });

    console.log(this.carbs);
   //pass the data here
     this.data = {"Macros":[{"Macros":"Prot","time":this.protein,"color":"#3fa9f5","hover":"#57c0f5"},{"Macros":"Carb","time":this.carbs,"color":"rgb(236, 240, 241)","hover":"rgb(236, 240, 241)"},{"Macros":"Fat","time":this.fat,"color":"rgb(52, 73, 94)","hover":"rgb(52, 73, 94)"}]};


}
```

Comment: Are you sure that this.user is not undefined?

Comment: this user returns the json, console.log(res[0].carbs) inside the res => also outputs the right value.

Comment: ionViewDidLoad() {} use this function. Copy paste your code inside of it and check what happens.

Comment: Undefined there as well.

Comment: reason is highly probable that before this.carbs = res[0].carbs; line console.log(this.carbs); is initiated.

Comment: Where you are going to use this.carbs?

Comment: I mean will you pass it to the another function or will use in html?

Comment: I'm passing the data from json to another function that uses tthe values in a Piechart :)

Comment: Okay, it will solve the issue. I will write it as answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177805/discussion-between-shahriyar-mammadli-and-sdfgg45).

Comment: I added the json array for pie chart data inside with the variables, now i get data undefined.

Comment: checkout the answer again, I updated it

Answer (score 1):

It is because that  `console.log(this.carbs);` is initiated before `this.carbs = res[0].carbs;` is completed. Therefore, instead of calling your function outside the scope, call it inside of your scope.

Call your function from:

```
 this.user.toPromise().then(res => {

        this.carbs = res[0].carbs;
        this.fat = res[0].fat;
        this.protein = res[0].protein;
        this.yourFunction(res[0].protein, res[0].carbs, res[0].fat );
    });
```

.
.
.

```
yourFunction(protein, carbs, fat){
 this.data = {"Macros":[{"Macros":"Prot","time":protein,"color":"#3fa9f5","hover":"#57c0f5"},{"Macros":"Carb","time":carbs,"color":"rgb(236, 240, 241)","hover":"rgb(236, 240, 241)"},{"Macros":"Fat","time":fat,"color":"rgb(52, 73, 94)","hover":"rgb(52, 73, 94)"}]};
}
```

Comment: The same: ERROR TypeError: "this.data is undefined"

Comment: Come to chat please, unless stackoverflow will block comments